# Chunk-oriented processing or Tasklet

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-batch

The job consists on:

1. consuming a list of emails from a Kafka REST client (that's the
   restriction, we can not use a native java client)
2. decode the content from Base64
3. store it on database (a record by email)

I'm not sure if I can / should implement it as a chunk-oriented process or do I keep it simple as a Tasklet?

I already did it as a Tasklet, so I would like to know if it's possible the other way and if it has any benefits.

This is what I consume from the REST client

```
[
  {
    "value": "base64encoded"
  },
  {
    "value": "base64encoded"
  },
  ...
]
```

where the encoded values are arrays of email addresses `["item1", "item2"]`.

As the content are arrays of strings I return a single `List<String>` on the `read()` method of my custom `ItemReader`, but I don't think that is right as it should return an item, isn't?

I also do the decoding on the reader  or should I do it on a ItemProcessor?.

As a writer, I chooseed `JdbcBatchItemWriter<List<String>>` but I'm not sure how I should configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would begin that evaluation with the question, what happens if something goes wrong?  Spring Batch provides a lot of facilities for handling errors via listeners, retry and skip mechanisms, etc.  Most of those are not available via a raw `Tasklet` implementation.  Second, if you are doing item based processing (aka iterating over things one item at a time), even if you are adding parallelism to that, I'd still recommend using chunk based processing.  Only after going through both of those thoughts, would I consider doing a raw `Tasklet` implementation.

Comment: The main issue I see here is that I can not chunk the read process as I get all the content in one call only.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't chunk it...it just means that you read it once on startup and chunk it as each call to `read()` is called.